# Efficient algorithm to search for a target in a matrix given only the path it took?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

The problem is as follows: we have an N by N matrix, A. A bird starts at (0, 0) and traces a path, where at each time step it flies in one of the four cardinal directions, staying inside the matrix and never returning to an already-visited square. It eventually stops on some square. The entries of the matrix are as follows:

A[i,j] = NULL if the bird never visited A[i,j].

A[i,j] = RIGHT if the bird visited A[i,j] and then flew to the square to the right.

(similarly for UP, DOWN, LEFT)

A[i,j] = BIRD if the bird stops at that square.

Is there an efficient algorithm to find BIRD?

Comment: Can you give a simple example input and output here. By the description, it seems that just by following the matrix, starting from (0,0), you will ultimately reach BIRD

Comment: The original question said 'Is there an O(n) algorithm to find BIRD', which was found and answered. If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify what you mean by 'efficient' in your recent edit.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** The original posted version (bisecting by rows and columns alternating) with O(N) is not giving the correct answer in all cases - as pointed out by @Pychopath . When only bisecting the rows the algorithm works but is O(N log N). But there is still an O(N) algorithm possible:

By scanning two adjacent rows (or columns) one can count the number of crossings of the bird's path in both directions with the line between the rows (columns). When we know the side on which the path starts we can decide on which side the path ends.

Given a rectangle (sub-matrix) we know if the path starts inside by checking if (0,0) is inside the rectangle. Scanning along all four sides for crossings in and out we can decide if the path ends inside or outside the rectangle.

If we know that the path ends inside a given square with side `n` (lets assume `n` is even) we can divide it into 4 squares of equal size and find the one where the path ends - with at most `2*3*2*n = 12n` queries (sides lying on the border of the original matrix would need no crossing counts, but this is not exploited here).

Lets assume that `N` is a power of 2 (if not we can replace it by the next power of 2). Then with each step we can halve the size of the square where we know that the path must end.

Altogether we have a maximum of roughly `12N + 12N/2 + 12N/4 + ... = 24N` queries.

Here is Python code:

```
O,L,R,U,D,B = range(6) # NULL, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, BIRD
M = [
[R,R,D,O,O,O,O,O,O,O], # path starts at (0,0), i.e. top left corner
[O,O,D,O,R,R,D,O,O,O],
[O,O,D,O,U,O,D,O,O,O],
[D,L,L,O,U,O,D,O,O,O],
[R,R,R,R,U,O,D,B,L,O], # path ends at 'B'
[O,O,O,O,O,O,D,O,U,O],
[O,D,L,L,L,L,L,O,U,O],
[O,D,O,O,O,O,O,O,U,O],
[O,D,O,R,R,D,O,O,U,O],
[O,R,R,U,O,R,R,R,U,O]
]

def getMatrixEntry(rowIdx, colIdx):
  if rowIdx < 0 or rowIdx >= len(M):         return O
  if colIdx < 0 or colIdx >= len(M[rowIdx]): return O
  return M[rowIdx][colIdx]

# given a rectangular range in which the path ends,
# find the quadrant in which the path ends
def getQuadrantOfPathEnd(rowStart, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd):
  if rowEnd - rowStart <= 4 or colEnd - colStart <= 4:
    # just scan for B
    for rowIdx in range(rowStart, rowEnd):
      for colIdx in range(colStart, colEnd):
        if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx, colIdx) == B:
          return rowIdx,rowIdx+1,colIdx,colIdx+1
    assert False, f"path end expected inside {(rowStart, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd)}, but not found"

  # split rectangle into quadrants at center row and column
  # (quadrants are indexed in matrix like fashion [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], [1][1] )
  rowSplit = (rowStart + rowEnd) // 2
  colSplit = (colStart + colEnd) // 2
  # lets scan the horizontal borders of the quadrants for vertical crossings
  # (the six border lines at top left, top right, center left, center right, bottom left, bottom right
  # are indexed in matrix like fashion)
  # The crossing sums are 
  # - incremented for each crossing from top to bottom and 
  # - decremented for each crossing from bottom to top
  vertCrossSums = []
  for rowIdx in [rowStart-1, rowSplit-1, rowEnd-1]:
    vertCrossSumLeft = 0
    for colIdx in range(colStart, colSplit):
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx) == D:
        vertCrossSumLeft += 1
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx+1,colIdx) == U:
        vertCrossSumLeft -= 1
    vertCrossSumRight = 0
    for colIdx in range(colSplit, colEnd):
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx) == D:
        vertCrossSumRight += 1
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx+1,colIdx) == U:
        vertCrossSumRight -= 1
    vertCrossSums.append((vertCrossSumLeft, vertCrossSumRight))
  # lets scan the vertical borders of the quadrants for horizontal crossings
  # (the six border lines at top left, top center, top right, bottom left, bottom center, bottom right
  # are indexed in matrix like fashion)
  # The crossing sums are 
  # - incremented for each crossing from left to right and 
  # - decremented for each crossing from right to left
  horCrossSums = []
  for colIdx in [colStart-1, colSplit-1, colEnd-1]:
    horCrossSumTop = 0
    for rowIdx in range(rowStart, rowSplit):
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx) == R:
        horCrossSumTop += 1
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx+1) == L:
        horCrossSumTop -= 1
    horCrossSumBottom = 0
    for rowIdx in range(rowSplit, rowEnd):
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx) == R:
        horCrossSumBottom += 1
      if getMatrixEntry(rowIdx,colIdx+1) == L:
        horCrossSumBottom -= 1
    horCrossSums.append((horCrossSumTop, horCrossSumBottom))
  print("  vertical   crossing sums", vertCrossSums)
  print("  horizontal crossing sums", horCrossSums)

  # lets find the quadrant where the path ends
  for subVertIdx in range(2):
    for subHorIdx in range(2):
      quadrant = (
        [rowStart, rowSplit][subVertIdx],
        [rowSplit, rowEnd]  [subVertIdx],
        [colStart, colSplit][subHorIdx],
        [colSplit, colEnd]  [subHorIdx]
      )
      pathStartsInside = 1 if quadrant[0] == 0 and quadrant[2] == 0 else 0
      # sum the crossings along the 4 borders of a quadrant
      # (+1 for each crossing going into, -1 for each crossing going out of the quadrant)
      quadrCrossSum = (
        vertCrossSums [subVertIdx][subHorIdx] - vertCrossSums [subVertIdx+1][subHorIdx] +
        horCrossSums[subHorIdx][subVertIdx] - horCrossSums[subHorIdx+1][subVertIdx]
      )
      pathEndsInside = pathStartsInside + quadrCrossSum
      assert 0 <= pathEndsInside <= 1, f"pathEndsInside {pathEndsInside} = {pathStartsInside} + {quadrCrossSum} not in [0,1] for {quadrant}"
      if pathEndsInside == 1:
        return quadrant
  assert False, "quadrant with path end inside expected, but not found"

# rectangle with path end inside
rTop,rBot,rLft,rRgt = 0,len(M),0,len(M[0])
while rBot-rTop > 1 or rRgt - rLft > 1:
  print("rectangle", (rTop,rBot,rLft,rRgt))
  rTop,rBot,rLft,rRgt = getQuadrantOfPathEnd(rTop,rBot,rLft,rRgt)
assert M[rTop][rLft] == B
print("bird at", rTop,rLft)
```

giving the following output:

```
rectangle (0, 10, 0, 10)
  vertical   crossing sums [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
  horizontal crossing sums [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
rectangle (0, 5, 5, 10)
  vertical   crossing sums [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
  horizontal crossing sums [(1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
rectangle (2, 5, 7, 10)
bird at 4 7
```

Comment: This is brilliant. One question-- why do you need two adjacent rows instead of just one?

Comment: and if the bird never moved and only a single square says "bird" you'd still need to visit all cells, making the worst case N^2

Comment: @StenPetrov Not true: the bird starts at (0,0). On the first step, if after checking the middle two rows they are all null, we know the bird is in the half of the array with (0,0).

Comment: @kcsquared I missed that part, you're right. It's still not linear but log(N) in this case

Comment: @StenPetrov What do you mean by 'not linear'? I can't see anything wrong with the `6N` upper bound on queries.

Comment: You do not need to scan 2 adjacent rows.  It TELLS you when you go LEFT or RIGHT.  So scanning a single row tells you where the crossings are and what direction they are in.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Consider [these two paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icH60.png). After determining that the bird is in the upper half, you'd see the same RIGHT RIGHT LEFT across the upper vertical line for both paths. But in the first case the bird is on the *left* side while in the second case the bird is on the *right* side. I think it's at least not as easy as you made it sound so far. Maybe you can keep track of additional information from previous splits to still make it work in O(N). Always counting across the whole row/column would make it O(N log N), I think. (also @kcsquared)

Comment: @Pychopath You're right, that's a very nice catch. It *might* be fixable: if on step `i` you have a vertical line and you see a sequence of crossings, (lefts and rights), IF you can work out what order the bird made those crossings in, then: you can calculate the `#ups - #downs` sum (at any y-coordinate) that are in your current area but are about to be removed from view in the next bisection. This would fix the algorithm. For example, if on the first horizontal bisection you see 'Up Down Down' as crossings, the order must be '2 3 1'. However the general pattern is unclear.

Comment: @kcsquared (also at btilly) the adjacent rows (columns) are needed to also find out from which side the path comes. It could come from the same side it goes to - then there is no crossing

Comment: @Pychopath you are right: the originally posted algorithm does not give the correct result for the left path in your image. The problem is that the crossings of sub-matrices are not known for all borders. When scanning all borders of the sub-matrices the algorithm works - and is still O(N)

Comment: After testing the posted code with randomly generated input, everything appears to be working. It also runs in `O(N)` by inspection. Refactoring into functions would help readability, along with comments/explanation of how the four variables starting with `goDownCountLeft` are being calculated. It looks like you're doing some clever indexing to avoid double counting corners, but it's hard to tell whether it's correct.

Comment: @kcsquared thank you for the feedback. I tried to improve the readability of the code. The "clever indexing" only saves the double checking of the crossings at the center rows/columns. Extracting more functions is left as an exercise for the reader :-). (Generalizing code for different coordinate directions while keeping the code simple and readable is not an easy task.)